# httppost method of controller not firing using ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a simple search page, on click of search button, results should be displayed.

View:

```
@model MvcSearchEngine.Models.SearchResultsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
    <input id="txtSearch" type="text" />
    <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>

<div id="data-grid">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#search").click(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                uri:"@Url.Action("PostSearchData","Search")",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: '{ "filter": "' + $("#txtSearch").val() + '" }',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Search/
        SearchServiceClient searchProxy = new SearchServiceClient();
        AdvertisementServiceClient AdvProxy = new AdvertisementServiceClient();
        SearchResultsModel searchModel = new SearchResultsModel();
        List<SearchServiceData> searchResult = new List<SearchServiceData>();
        List<AdvertisementServiceData> advertisementResult = new List<AdvertisementServiceData>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public SearchResultsModel PostSearchData(SearchParam filter)
        {
            try
            {
                if (filter != null)
                {
                    searchResult = searchProxy.GetSearchResultCriteria(Convert.ToString(filter));
                    advertisementResult = AdvProxy.GetAdvertisements(Convert.ToString(filter));
                    searchModel.SearchData = searchResult;
                    searchModel.AdvertisementData = advertisementResult;
                }
                return searchModel;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

`PostSearchData` controller method is not getting called from ajax method on search button only view is returned. am i doing somewhere mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your action is marked with the following attribute so it can respond to POST calls:`[HttpPost]`

example:

`[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PostSearchData(string filter)
 {
 ..
 ..
 }`